# Doctrine 2.4 PreUpdate get Original Data returns new data?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have this code in my Doctrine2 Entity Listener that listens to the PreUpdate event.
Why does the original entity data contains the new data instead of the old one?

```
/**
 * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
 */
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $original = $uow->getOriginalEntityData($args->getEntity());

    echo $original['name']; // THIS OUTPUTS THE NEW NAME ???
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the change set with the following method:

```
getEntityChangeSet()
```

If you want to test if a field has changed you can use:

```
hasChangedField($field)
```

If you want to get the old value of a field:

```
getOldValue($field)
```

For more information see:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html#_getEntityChangeSet

Comment: Thanks for this @sebbo but this will only give me access to changed attributes not all the old attributes (which I need).

Comment: Ah alright sorry. Thought you would only need certain fields.